# How to pick images from SD card gallery and not other sources

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I'm creating an app that lets users pick a picture from the phone gallery. All works fine for images on the SD card but when the user selects a picture from Picassa, the application crashes.

Code for calling gallery:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_FROM_GALLERY_ACTION);
```

Code for receiving image:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
File galeryFile = new File(filePath);
FileUtils.copyFile(galeryFile, imageFile);
processImage(imageFile);
```

Errror:

```
08-30 14:51:04.268: E/ActivityThread(31379): Failed to find provider info for com.android.gallery3d.provider
08-30 14:51:04.278: E/AndroidRuntime(31379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 14:51:04.278: E/AndroidRuntime(31379): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=4353, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5735585761449205042 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.my_gallery_app/com.example.my_gallery_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Null pointer occures on line:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

[I read this workaround.](http://jimmi1977.blogspot.hu/2012/01/android-api-quirks-getting-image-from.html) But comments aren't promising. I would like to restrict gallery from showing the user Facebook, Picassa or other pictures and let her pick images only from the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps--->

Declaration--->

```
    private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    Cursor imagecursor;
```

Inside onCreate()----->

```
            String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);


    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

        arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
```

Create GridView in Layout and use here--->

```
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that uses the built in Gallery to display images, but I'll try it out, and get back to you!